# Scala macro: get companion object from class type

Tags: scala, class, scala-macros, companion-object, scala-quasiquotes

I cannot manage to get the companion object / singleton from a class type in Scala macro / quasiquotes. Tried to follow https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/type-details.html#singleton-type, the given example works but it is based on a literal string to quasiquote to get the companion object directly, which I cannot quite achieve the same thing if I start off from an extracted class type of a param after some quasiquote unlifting.

I have simplified and tried to highlight the intended usage, and current macro implementation below:

```scala
// Intended usage
package utils

sealed trait Base

object Base {
  import macros._

  @Component
  final case class X(v: XInner) extends Base
}

final case class XInner(v: Int)

Base.X(123)  // No need to do Base.X(XInner(123))
```

The current macro implementation

```scala
package macros

import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation
import scala.annotation.compileTimeOnly

class Component() extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro ComponentMacro.impl
}

private class ComponentMacro(val c: whitebox.Context) {
  import c.universe._

  // To map function result while allowing the use of params forwarding syntax like `apply _`
  // e.g. `def y = (X.apply _).mapResult(Y(_))`
  implicit class Func1Extra[I1, O1, O2](f: I1 => O1) {
    def mapResult(g: O1 => O2): I1 => O2 = (i1: I1) => g(f(i1))
  }

  def impl(annottees: Tree*): Tree = annottees match {
    case (clsDef: ClassDef) :: Nil =>
      clsDef match {
        case q"final case class $className(..$fields) extends ..$parents" if fields.length == 1 => {
          val fieldType = fields(0).tpt
          val singletonType = tq"$fieldType.type"
          val tq"$singleton.type" = singletonType
          q"""
          $clsDef
          object ${clsDef.name.toTermName} {
            def apply = (${singleton}.apply _).mapResult(new ${clsDef.name}(_))
          }
          """
        }

        case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Invalid annotation target")
      }

    case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Invalid annotation target")
  }
}
```

The error while compiling is:

```
value apply is not a member of Utils.XInner
```

The error message seems to suggest that the `apply` method was done on the `XInner` class type, rather than the companion object of `XInner`.

Any idea as to how to get the component object of the same type name? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code must type check before expansion. I've only tried macro annotations for a few tests, but I wouldn't be surprised if case class members have not been added when macro is invoked. I recently had an issue with something not available for macro annotation.

Comment: Apparently macro annots are expanded before case class apply is synthetized.

Comment: Hmm it does work if I attempt to use literal directly, i.e.
`def apply = (utils.XInner.apply _)`

Alternatively, doing
`val tq"$singleton.type" = tq"utils.XInner.type"` works too for `singleton` interpolation.

But it's true that I'm not familiar with the ordering of the "synthesis", so that might affect too.

Comment: I forgot to say use `-Vmacro-lite` on 2.13 when debugging.

Comment: BTW, I was wrong: unlike def macros, macro-annots expand early, so it does support your use case (though it's a little too magical for my preference).

Comment: Why not to use class constructor rather than compiler-generated `apply` method of companion object?